# Best way to pass JSON from Browser to PHP using Ajax.Request

Tags: php, json, prototypejs, ajax.request

Hi I have a JSON object that is a 2-dimentional array and I need to pass it to PHP using Ajax.Request (only way I know how). ...Right now I manually serialized my array using a js function...and get the data in this format: s[]=1&d[]=3&[]=4 etc. ....

my question is: Is there a way to pass the JSON object more directly/efficientely?..instead of serializing it myself?

Thanks for any suggestions,
Andrew

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use Prototype's function [toJSON()](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/array/tojson) to convert an array into a JSON object. After passing it to server via Ajax call, simply use PHP's function [json_decode()](http://us.php.net/json_decode) to decode the object.

Answer (score 5):

Pass the object as a JSON-string to PHP, and in PHP use the builtin json_decode to get a PHP-object from the string.

In Javascript, use a "stringify" function on your object to get it as a string, library available for example here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Answer (score 3):

In que Javascript side (with Prototye):

```
var myJSON= Object.toJSON(youArray);
```

In que Php side:

```
$myjson = $_POST['myjson'];

$arrayJSON= json_decode(stripslashes($myjson), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check 
http://www.openjs.com/scripts/data/ued_url_encoded_data/ 
to encode nested data directly correct, since Object.toQueryString() doesn't accept nested data...